# Change a view property from an unrelated controller

Tags: ember.js

I have the following view:

```
App.MessageTrayView = Bootstrap.AlertMessage.extend({
    message: 'This is a message.',
});
```

Displayed in this template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="nodes">
    <article>
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>

          {{view App.MessageTrayView id="message-tray-view"}}

          <div id="legend" class="">
            <legend class="">Nodes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge">{{controllers.nodesIndex.length}} records</span>
            <div class="pull-right">
              <a {{action destroyAllRecords}}><i class="icon-remove-circle"></i><a/>
              {{#linkTo "nodes.new" class="btn btn-primary"}}Add Node{{/linkTo}}
            </div>
            </legend>
          </div>

          {{outlet}}

        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </article>
  </script>
```

And this unrelated controller:

```
App.NodesIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    destroyAllRecords: function () {
        console.log('destroyAllRecords called');
        App.MessageTrayView.set('message', 'All nodes have been deleted');
    },
});
```

I want to change the message displayed as soon as the `destroyAllRecords` is triggered. This is not working (the error message in the console is telling me that I am doing something * very* wrong). How can I change the `message` property, so that the changes are directly visible on the page?

You can see the code live [here](http://jsbin.com/uletez/1#/nodes/index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way of doing this could be to define a property on the `App` namespace:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  messageTrayContent: ''
});
```

then bind to it in your view using the suffix `Binding` after your property name:

```
App.MessageTrayView = Bootstrap.AlertMessage.extend({
  messageBinding: 'App.messageTrayContent'
});
```

Now doing:

```
App.NodesIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  destroyAllRecords: function () {
    console.log('destroyAllRecords called');
    App.set('messageTrayContent', 'All nodes have been deleted');
  },
});
```

should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I had seen examples of defining a binding to an application property in the view, but I hoped there was a direct programmatic way of modifying a view property.

Comment: @gonvaled, yes I understand you, the thing is that since view's are meant to be loosely coupled the binding mechanism is the preferred way